# Conditional Routing in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom v5. Some of my routes are restricted to specific user roles. It is to prevent rendering components that I don't want certain users to see.

Here is my code,

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/institute/*">
        {user.role === "teacher" || user.role === "student"  ? (
            <Route path="/institute/">
                <Route exact path="/institute/lectures" component={Lectures}
                />
                <Route exact path="/institute/modules" component={Modules}
                />
            </Route>
        ) : (
            <Redirect to="/" />
        )}
        {user.role === "student" ? (
            <Route exact path="/institute/student" component={Student}
            />
        ) : (
            <Redirect to="/" />
        )}
    </Route>
    ...
</Switch>
```

The problem here is when I'm trying to access `/institute/lectures"` or `/institute/modules`
with `student` user role I'm redirecting to "/"

How to setup this route successfully? Are there other suggestions that would be better in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only overt issue I see with the code is that the route rendering on `path="/institute/*"` is wrapping several other routes. When `Route` components are not directly rendered by a `Switch` component so they are ***exclusively*** matched and rendered, then they work like normal when rendered by a router, they ***inclusively*** render all matches.

I don't see any issue when the `user.role` is `"student"` and all routes are accessible. The issue I see is when `user.role` is `"teacher"`.

Example:

Assume `user = { role: "teacher" }` and the URL path is `"/institue/lectures"`

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/institute/*">
    {user.role === "teacher" || user.role === "student" ? (
      <Route path="/institute/">
        <Route exact path="/institute/lectures" component={Lectures} /> // (1)*
        <Route exact path="/institute/modules" component={Modules} />
      </Route>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to="/" />
    )}
    {user.role === "student" ? (
      <Route exact path="/institute/student" component={Student} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect to="/" /> // (2)**
    )}
  </Route>
  ...
</Switch>
```

The `path="/institute/*"` route matches and returns its content which consists of several nested routes that will now inclusively match. `user.role` is `"teacher"` so the `path="/institute/"` route renders its content, then `path="/institute/lectures"` is also matched and renders its content, the `Lectures` component, #1.

Since `user.role === "student"` evaluates false, the `Redirect` component renders and when it does, it unconditionally redirects to the home `"/"` path, #2.

This will occur for any user with `role !== "student"`.

Adding another `Switch` component *inside* `<Route path="/institute/*">` route will fix this as now only the ***first*** matching `Route` or `Redirect` will be matched and rendered, exclusively.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/institute/*">
    <Switch>
      {user.role === "teacher" || user.role === "student" ? (
        <Route path="/institute/">
          <Route exact path="/institute/lectures" component={Lectures} />
          <Route exact path="/institute/modules" component={Modules} />
        </Route>
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/" />
      )}
      {user.role === "student" ? (
        <Route exact path="/institute/student" component={Student} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/" />
      )}
    </Switch>
  </Route>
  ...
</Switch>
```

[image: Edit conditional-routing-in-react-router]

This code is a little convoluted and could be simplified a bit. Create a custom route component to handle checking an access role and redirecting.

```
const RoleRoute = ({ roles = [], user = {}, ...props }) =>
  !roles.length || roles.includes(user.role) ? (
    <Route {...props} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to="/" />
  );
```

Render the routes directly into the `Switch`.

```
<Switch>
  <RoleRoute
    roles={["teacher", "student"]}
    user={user}
    path="/institute/lectures"
    component={Lectures}
  />
  <RoleRoute
    roles={["teacher", "student"]}
    user={user}
    path="/institute/modules"
    component={Modules}
  />
  <RoleRoute
    roles={["student"]}
    user={user}
    path="/institute/student"
    component={Student}
  />
  ...
</Switch>
```

[image: Edit conditional-routing-in-react-router (forked)]